# How can I get more answers to my question?

Tags: support, questions, unanswered-questions

I asked a question on this site several months ago, and I still have not received a working answer. Is there some way I can get an answer to this question or get more people to view it without putting a bounty?

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn’t link to your question in the body, I’ll assume you want general advice. The people that have been here for a long time have assembled our collective wisdom in the help section on asking.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Have you read the parts about promoting, editing and asking? I’d be happy to look at your question and see if any of the advice seems more useful for your specific instance.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378112/cant-update-or-uninstall-itunes-for-windows